# Office VSTO AddIn stops responding after invoking Regex several times

Tags: c#, regex, vba, vsto

I am writing a VSTO C# code that would copy the content of active projects in Visual Basic editor in any Office application and process it following some rules. The AddIn adds a button to the VBE toolbar and an event for a click.

When debugging, it works fine the first couple of times (between 8 and 12) I click the button but then it just stops responding to the clicks. Restarting the application does not help, but repeat debugging does (again, for the first 8 - 12 clicks).

I experimented with the code and found that it behaves this way whenever the code uses Regex, even something rather basic. Any ideas what may be going wrong?

This piece of code is for the illustration only. All it is supposed to do is to produce a message box "OK" after it applies Regex to each code module content. And so it does - for the first 8 to 12 times. After that, the button clicks produce no response whatsoever.

No error messages are shown, except when it is building the solution, among many lines it shows **Exception thrown: 'System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException' in System.Deployment.dll**, which does not seem to affect the program during the first clicks.

```
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using VBA = Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace CodeControl
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            AddButton();
        }
        public void AddButton()
        {               
            Office.CommandBar cbr = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.VBE.CommandBars["Edit"];
            Office.CommandBarButton button = cbr.Controls.Add(Type: 1, Temporary: true).Control;
            button.FaceId = 10;
            button.Visible = true;
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.VBE.Events.CommandBarEvents[button].Click += 
                new VBA._dispCommandBarControlEvents_ClickEventHandler(DoWork);
        }
        void DoWork(object CommandBarControl, ref bool handled, ref bool CancelDefault)
        {            
            foreach (VBA.VBComponent component in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents)
            {
                VBA.CodeModule module = component.CodeModule;
                if (module.CountOfLines < 4)
                    continue;
                string text = module.Lines[1, module.CountOfLines];
                foreach (string lineText in Regex.Split(text, @"(?:\r\n|\n|\r)"))
                   Console.WriteLine(lineText);
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(module.Name);
            }            
        }
        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e){}

        #region VSTO generated code

        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }        
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are saying if you comment out the regex, everything works fine?

Comment: TheGeneral, that's exactly what I am saying. It works fine on any number of clicks. I clicked some 40 - 50 times as well as ran it in loops by 10,000 times and it kept responding.

Comment: Do you have the option to show add-in interface errors turned on? It's somewhere in the Word options and turned off by default.

Comment: Chris, I turned it on, but it did not help - nothing changed.